# Sorting grouped query in chronological order in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The following LINQ query obtains the previous 12 months data and aggregates it by month.

I'd like to order this in chronological order, with the current month being the most recent in the query.

What's the best way to achieve this?

```
public IEnumerable<EventMonthlySummaryMonthly> GetLastYearEventGrid()
        {

            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMilliseconds(1);

            var summary = from p in db.Events
                          where (p.StartDate > currentDate) && (p.StartDate != null)
                          let k = new
                          {
                              Month = p.StartDate.Month
                          }
                          group p by k into t
                          select new EventMonthlySummaryMonthly
                          {
                              Month = t.Key.Month,
                              EventsWhatsOn = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 1),
                              EventsRegular = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 2),
                              EventsExhibitions = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 3),
                              EventsAll = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId != null),
                          };

            return summary;
        }
```

Comment: you can use sort descriptor to sort summary Listm but you want it to sort inside the linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sorting on the max date from the grouped month Descending. If the range spans several years this will give you the months that contains the latest dates first.

```
orderby t.Max(p => p.StartDate) descending
select new EventMonthlySummaryMonthly
{
   Month = t.Key.Month,
   EventsWhatsOn = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 1),
   EventsRegular = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 2),
   EventsExhibitions = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 3),
   EventsAll = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId != null),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this still doesn't take into account the year and orders by month ascending.

Comment: This should give you the months with the most recent dates first. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Projecting into EventMonthlySummaryMonthly seems to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IEnumerable<EventMonthlySummaryMonthly> GetLastYearEventGrid()
    {

        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMilliseconds(1);

        var summary = (from p in db.Events
                      where (p.StartDate > currentDate) && (p.StartDate != null)
                      let k = new
                      {
                          Month = p.StartDate.Month
                      }
                      group p by k into t
                      select new EventMonthlySummaryMonthly
                      {
                          Month = t.Key.Month,
                          EventsWhatsOn = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 1),
                          EventsRegular = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 2),
                          EventsExhibitions = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId == 3),
                          EventsAll = t.Count(p => p.EventTypeId != null),
                      }).OrderByDescending(item=>item.Month);

        return summary;
    }
```

Comment: The range may span multiple years so this does not give the desired result. Thanks for the response though.